# Moon Reader Pro Text Wrapping

Tags: ebook-reader, moon-reader

I have tried MoonReader Pro but when I increase the font size the text is not wrapped and the increased text overflows the screen in my tab. I want it to behave like as note pad does with its size and with increase in font size.

Comment: Sounds like you should report this to the developer. It's unlikely that anyone else would be able to change the behaviour of the app.

Comment: @DanHulme I thought there was some option that I did not know of. Is there any alternative app to this?